# which is better using FirestorePagingAdapter or manually paginate

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am asking about which is better using `FirestorePagingAdapter` or paginate it manually. By every swipe to refresh get a request with adding a new 20 items

The point is that:

I have an app have 10k users and I have a forum. This forum have 1000 posts and I want to reduce its costing because in one getting its get the 1000 post. S which one is better using `FirestorePagingAdapter` or paginate it that every swipe its adding 20 posts

Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank van Puffelen explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273741/firestorepagingadapter-not-receiving-realtime-updates):

> The `FirestorePagingAdapter` in the FirebaseUI library is designed to get data, not to listen for realtime updates.

And Doug Stevenson in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670606/android-paging-library-firestore-crashes-with-illegalstateexception):

> Unfortunately, you can't have both realtime updates and paging at the same time.

So if you want to `FirestorePagingAdapter` or the `Paging Library`, it means you'll loose the realtime feature.

> So which one is better using `FirestorePagingAdapter` or paginate

If you need to implement paging for your items and have in the same time the realtime feature, then please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50742175/5246885)** and instead of using a `get()` call, you need to use `addSnapshotListener()` as explained in the official documentation regarding [listening to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection).

Comment: thank u for your answer .. iam sorry i couldnt open yesterday .. your answer really helped me but .. i was hope to know .. is FirestorePagingAdapter gonna reduce the cost of my firestore database by reducing requests as i explained in my question

Comment: Good to hear that it helped. It will, since `FirestorePagingAdapter` does not listen for realtime updates. So when you get the data, you won't have any additional reads when the data is changed.