# Android Paging library 2 onResult forces fragment to be destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-paging

I have populated my PagedList from a datasource and I can see all the data as expected. However, when I kill switch to another fragment and launch a new instance of the same fragment, I see the data being returned from the backend but I the fragment is destroyed before I am able to load the data. I was able to debug into the illegalStateException that was thrown when result was returned as follows,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: callback.onResult already called, cannot call again.
```

Can someone direct me how to properly cleanup after the library when I close the fragment the first time around?

My issue is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670606/android-paging-library-firestore-crashes-with-illegalstateexception) except my app is not crashing but the fragment is destroyed.